# Conservation, Maxwell tensor

Tags: electromagnetism

Can someone please explain to me how the conservation of the energy momentum tensor $$\nabla_\beta T^{\alpha \beta}=0$$

imply the conservation of the Maxwell tensor $$\nabla_\beta F^{\alpha \beta}=0$$?

Additional info:

Note that the $\nabla_\beta$ denotes the covariant derivative.

Energy momentum tensor

[Maxwell tensor = electromagnetic tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_tensor)

Comment: I don't know why the link for the "energy momentum tensor" is not working...

Comment: Where are you getting this fact from?

Comment: @joshphysics:  It is from some lecture notes.

Comment: Well obviously it only has a chance of working for some specific energy-momentum tensor, not just some arbitrary one that mightn't even include the electromagnetic field. Also this particular derivation clearly breaks in the presence of electrically charged matter since you've written the *source free* Maxwell equations (half of them). A few more details would help. What $T_{\mu\nu}$ are you starting with? And what have you tried? If the implication is true for your setup it should be a straightforward exercise. Where are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim isn't correct and even the way how the second equation is called, "conservation of Maxwell tensor", is deeply misleading.  It makes no sense to call it a conservation law because the integral $\int d^3 x\,F^{0\mu}$ isn't any natural conserved quantity.

The second equation is called one of the Maxwell's equations. Moreover, the right form has sources on the right hand side
$$\partial_{\mu} F^{\mu\nu}=j^{\nu}$$
The time component is the charge density and the spatial components make up the current. It is possible to use the definition of the stress-energy tensor in terms of the Maxwell tensor etc. to prove the conservation of the stress-energy tensor of Maxwell's equations (because the stress-energy tensor is bilinear in the Maxwell tensor) but it's not possible to do the opposite, especially because the simplified Maxwell's equation without a $j^\mu$ isn't really true.

Comment: @bubble In my opinion, the question that the original question's notation hints is the following: In the Einstein-Maxwell theory and without additional matter fields, is it possible to obtain the (sourceless) inhomogeneous Maxwell equations in a curved space-time from the covariant conservation of the Maxwell's stress-energy  tensor —which follows from the Einstein equations and the Bianchi identity? And the answer is *yes* unless either the electric and magnetic field are perpendicular or one of them is zero.